# Unexpected behavior of the “Money” field in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, php

I started developing a web sistem using Linux Ubuntu and at some point I had to do the following with the data type "money":

```
explode(" ", "R$ 3,000.00"); // [0] => "R$" and [1] => "3,000.00"
```

However when I installed the software in Windows I realized that the data is saved without space, that is, **"R$3,000.00"**. Soon, the code snippet fails to function properly.

Note: 1 could "fix" this using:

```
preg_replace("/[R$]+/", "$0 $1", "R$3,000.00"); // "R$ 3,000.00"
```

But certainly not a better way.

Note 2: The version of PostgreSQL used is 9.5

Would anyone have any suggestions for resolving this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Store it as an integer & deal with the formatting in the presentation layer. php has `currency_format()`

Comment: I can only recommend to stay away from the `money` data type. Use a `decimal` or an integer as Phil suggested. I personally find the money data type utterly useless.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [documentation on monetary types on PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-money.html):

> Since the **output of this data type is locale-sensitive**, it might not work to load money data into a database that has a different setting of lc_monetary. To avoid problems, before restoring a dump into a new database make sure lc_monetary has the same or equivalent value as in the database that was dumped.

(emphasis mine)

The interpretation of the local for `lc_monetary` is system-dependent, and doesn't work the same way in Ubuntu as in Windows.

Check [Best data type to store money values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030368/best-data-type-to-store-money-values-in-mysql/23353037#23353037), a good part of the answers are not MySQL specific, and they will give you a good understanding.

The natural tendency is to *not* deal with money types within databases, but use **numeric** types instead (and normally, with 4 decimals during calculations, not just 2), and handle the formatting at the app level. I should add also that, having a *money* type that doesn't store a *currency* doesn't make much sense to me.

---

With regard to locale information:

In Windows, you can actually set with very much detail how currency should be shown. The following picture shows the Windows 10 settings of my box:

[image: Windows currency settings]

They're quite different that those of my Ubuntu 16 box:

[image: Ubuntu]

And slightly different from the Mac that hosts them all:

[image: Mac OS X]

Comment: I do agree. I find the money type pretty useless as well.